# In javascript checking indexof() not working for initializing dynamic value using loop Example : new1

Tags: javascript

```js
var statusfield1 = "Yes";
var statusfield2 = "Yes";
for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
  if (("statusfield" + j).indexOf("Yes") >= 0) {

  }
}
```

It doesn't enter the If condition.

Comment: Java is not Javascript, nor is it C++. Please figure out the language you're using

Comment: If condition will be true if you use any of the variable `statusfield1` or `statusfield2` instead of hard coded string which doesn't contain `Yes` as text.

Comment: Converting a string to a variable name is fairly inconvenient. It's never really an issue however, because anytime you are counting on a variable to be named something like `statusfield1` `statusfield2` you should be using a different data structure. In this case probably an array: `var statusfields = [true, true]` Then the loop becomes very natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstanding here.

```
("statusfield"+j)
```

In range of 1 to 5 will end up `string` as `statusfield1`, `statusfield2` ... `statusfield5`

None of the resulting string `statusfield_` contains `Yes`, so `'statusfield1'.indexOf('Yes')` will always return you `-1`. Hence your `if` condition is never matched.

You will have to check within scope to fetch values of variables with dynamic names.

```js
var statusfield1 = "Yes";
var statusfield2 = "Yes, it is";
var statusfield4 = "Yessss";
var scope = this;
var field;
for (j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
  field = "statusfield" + j;
  if (undefined !== scope[field]) {
    if (-1 < scope[field].indexOf('Yes')) {
      console.log('got match', field);
    } else {
      console.log('no match !');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('no such variable exists, ', field);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Arvind said, get your understanding right, know your language properly.

I am assuming you want to dynamically check the string "yes" within a list variables. If that is the case, use a json object (Similar to map in java) as follows -

```
var map = {
"statusfield1" : "Yes",
"statusfield2" : "Yes",
"statusfield3" : "Yes",
"statusfield4" : "Yes",
"statusfield5" : "Yes"
}
```

And in iteration you can do this -

```
var keys =  Object.keys(map);
for (let j = 1; j <= keys.length; j++) {
  if (map["statusfield"+j].indexOf("Yes") >= 0) {
     console.log("Yes found");
  }
}
```

Pretty easy right?